# How does that exceprt from the JDK get compiled?

Tags: java, exception, java-7, checked-exceptions

The file is `java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.java`. JDK 7u45. The excerpt is:

```
public static SocketChannel open(SocketAddress remote)
    throws IOException
{
    SocketChannel sc = open();
    try {
        sc.connect(remote);
    } catch (Throwable x) {
        try {
            sc.close();
        } catch (Throwable suppressed) {
            x.addSuppressed(suppressed);
        }
        throw x;
    }
    assert sc.isConnected();
    return sc;
}
```

How does the compiler let passed that code? The signature declares **`IOException`**, but the method's body catches **`Throwable`** and retrows it. What don't I understand?

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

What you don't understand is that the compiler only checks checked exceptions, i.e. those that derive from `Exception` excluding those that derive from `RuntimeException`. Exceptions coming from elsewhere in the hierarchy starting at `Throwable` aren't subject to compilation rules.